# how to load image from url and insert into rich text box using chrome extension

Tags: javascript, html, dom, google-chrome-extension

I'm building a chrome extension that loads an image from a URL (as png/jpeg) and then inserts it into a page's rich text field, for ex: Gmail, Slack, etc. To further refine the problem: if you have an image URL, how'd you paste the image into the rich text editor? What is the best way to implement it?

Current answers when I looked include pasting an image from the user's clipboard, but I don't want to mess up with the user's clipboard as it'll lead to overwriting the existing item in it.

---

Update: so there's this deprecated `execCommand` API that can be used to insert images. Is that the best solution available?

```js
document.execCommand("insertimage",false,"https://via.placeholder.com/150")
```